# Send file or non-printable character in Immunity Debugger arguments

Tags: windows, shellcode, immunity-debugger

I am a beginner in Reverse Engineering.

I am on Windows and using Immunity Debugger.
I would like to send my payload on the .exe file.
The payload contains non-printable characters.

How I can launch the process in Immunity Debugger with this kind of payload ?

I cannot attach the process separately: it crashes instantly with the payload and I want to know why in Immunity Debugger.

I am OK with other solutions if any.

Thanks!